# How do I setup a callback for every frame of a CCAction?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to do:

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:self.Xposition scaleY:1];
id ease   = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:4];

[someObject[i] runAction:ease];
```

But I want to be able to hook into each frame of the action to do some stuff...  I am wondering if there is any way to accomplish this other than creating an update method on someObject?  I am trying to avoid doing that because it's a CCSprite, and I don't currently have an object wrapper for it..  It literally is just defined as something like CCSprite *someObject[4] in the header...  So I just wondered if there is any way to specify a per-frame callback in the context of runAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way to do this.

If this is what you really want to do rather than using an update method you could create a class similar to how the Ease actions work. Taking another action as a parameter and overriding update to modify its behavior.

For example if you called it CCCallBackAction it would be created as follows:

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:self.Xposition scaleY:1];
id ease   = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:4];
id callback = [CCCallBackAction actionWithAction:ease target:self selector:@selector(callback:)];

[someObject[i] runAction:callback];
```

In CCCallBackAction you would override update

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
     [target performSelector:SEL];
     [other update:dt];
}
```

---

***Note to avoid misunderstanding:** CCCallBackAction is not a cocos2d class, it is hypothetical in this example*

Comment: There is CCCallBlock (and CCCallFunc) though.

Comment: He wants the callback every frame though, not at the end of the scale.

Comment: Ben, I added an update method to my someObject class-- it's inheriting CCSprite, and it never gets called during animations..  I am confused because I saw it in the docs.. but it apparently is not getting triggered.

Comment: Update won't get called unless you schedule it. Inside your someObject init you can put [self scheduleUpdate];

Comment: Ok...  Interesting...  I don't quite get it..  So when I run scheduleUpdate, update is getting called per frame regardless of animation or not...  Which I guess it's fine-- I want to link two sprites together by movement, so this update method will constantly be setting sprite2's position relative to sprite1...  But, that does feel a little wasteful to be calling that setter every single frame, even when the values haven't changed.  Any suggestions on how to avoid that waste?

Comment: Are the sprites always moving the same amount or do they move away from each other? Can you add one as the child of the other so that they move together?

Comment: Oh.  I didn't think of doing it like that!  That's an interesting idea.  I shall try that right away!!

Comment: Hmm...  doing that, causes my game to crash immediately..  Is there a problem with doing:  [sprite1 addChild:sprite2], and then [layer addChild:sprite1]  ?  It's weird, when sprite1 adds sprite2 as a child, sprite1 gets its init method called over and over and over in an infinite loop...  That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Ah ok.. I see, apparently that was caused by sprite2 being added as a child to two thing..  I took it off of the parent, and just left it as a child of sprite1, and now it no longer crashes.  The only problem now is the sprite is not visible...  When it becomes a child of another sprite, is its position relative to that parent sprite?  or-- is it not visible for another reason?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16858/discussion-between-ben-and-patrick)

Answer (score 1):

Blocks to the rescue!!! :)

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:self.Xposition scaleY:1];
id ease   = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:4];
id call = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node) {
    // node is the sprite, you may have to cast it:
    CCSprite* someSprite = (CCSprite*)node;

    // do whatever you need to do with sprite here…
    someSprite.opacity = CCRANDOM_0_1() * 255;
}];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions:action, ease, call, nil];

[someObject[i] runAction:sequence];
```

Alternatively you can simply use the someObject[i] array as well and possibly even access the other sprites:

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:self.Xposition scaleY:1];
id ease   = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:4];
id call = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    CCSprite* someSprite = someObject[i];
    CCSprite* firstSprite = someObject[0];

    // do whatever you need to do with sprite here…
}];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions:action, ease, call, nil];

[someObject[i] runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: You have both action and ease in your sequence.

Comment: But that call only happens one time..  I need it to happen for every frame of the animation.  What I really am trying to do is make one  sprite follow, so that when the scaleX of someObject[0] is called, the position.x of someObject[1] changes relative to it..  That's what I am going for.